# My website sign-up page is not loading correctly

Tags: ruby, heroku

When a new user signs up on my website, it comes back

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

But if you then sign in using that same user it works.  I am thinking something is wrong with my sign-up page set up, but I cannot seem to figure out why it does not work.

I ran heroku logs and these are the errors I get.

```
Error in 186ms (ActiveRecord: 6.4ms)
2018-12-24T20:39:15.626963+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-12-24T20:39:15.626869 #4] FATAL -- : [3aaa57fe-9a15-468b-9371-313e8153d9bc]
2018-12-24T20:39:15.627057+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-12-24T20:39:15.626998 #4] FATAL -- : [3aaa57fe-9a15-468b-9371-313e8153d9bc] ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template user_mailer/welcome with "mailer". Searched in:
2018-12-24T20:39:15.627061+00:00 app[web.1]: * "user_mailer"
2018-12-24T20:39:15.627063+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2018-12-24T20:39:15.627143+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-12-24T20:39:15.627089 #4] FATAL -- : [3aaa57fe-9a15-468b-9371-313e8153d9bc]
2018-12-24T20:39:15.627246+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-12-24T20:39:15.627182 #4] FATAL -- : [3aaa57fe-9a15-468b-9371-313e8153d9bc] app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:13:in `welcome'
2018-12-24T20:39:15.627249+00:00 app[web.1]: [3aaa57fe-9a15-468b-9371-313e8153d9bc] app/controllers/user.registrations.controller.rb:5:in `create'
2018-12-24T20:39:15.627862+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=building-together.herokuapp.com request_id=3aaa57fe-9a15-468b-9371-313e8153d9bc fwd="75.187.204.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=191ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

This first code is the user.mailer.rb:13 FATAL

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def contact_form(email, name, message)
    @message = message
      mail(from: email,
            to: 'hostetlerp@gmail.com',
            subject: "A new contact form message from #{name}")
  end

  def welcome(user)
    @appname = "Bike Shop"
    mail(to: user.email,      (This is the line 13 FATAL)
          subject: "Welcome to #{@appname}!")
  end

  def thank_you
    @name = params[:name]
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = params[:message]
    UserMailer.contact_form(@email, @name, @message).deliver_now
  end
end
```

This is the second FATAL user.registrations.controller.rb:5

```
class UserRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
    if @user.persisted?
      UserMailer.welcome(@user).deliever_now  (This is the line 5 FATAL)
    end
  end
end
```

I cannot seem to figure out what I am missing here.  In the code for the course it all looks the same, but the page is not working.

Please help

Comment: "ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template user_mailer/welcome ...", does that file actually exist?

Comment: I figured out the problem for user mailer.  But I am still stuck on the UserRegistrationController